# reactstrap style display issue

Tags: javascript, reactjs, sass, reactstrap

I am trying to use reactstrap for a react project yet not successful. Here is the code.

```js
// React
import React, { Component } from "react";

import {
  Card,
  CardBody,
  CardTitle,
  Row,
  Col,
  InputGroup,
  InputGroupAddon,
  InputGroupText,
  Input
} from "reactstrap";

// Style
import "./App.scss";

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <Card>
          <CardBody>
            <CardTitle>Badges Scale to Parent</CardTitle>
            <InputGroup>
              <InputGroupAddon addonType="prepend">
                <InputGroupText>
                  <Input
                    addon
                    type="checkbox"
                    aria-label="Checkbox for following text input"
                  />
                </InputGroupText>
              </InputGroupAddon>
              <Input placeholder="Check it out" />
            </InputGroup>
            <input placeholder={"email"} />
            <input placeholder="name" />
            <input placeholder="mail" />
            <button>Send</button>
          </CardBody>
        </Card>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

I have hosted the app on codesandbox and here is the [link](https://codesandbox.io/s/client-0ytwb). I am expecting the look of the inputs to be exactly as the documentation but when implemented they look like regular input fields without any style. Here is the documentation page for reactstrap [link](https://reactstrap.github.io/components/input-group/). What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the documentation, the [first page](https://reactstrap.github.io/) says to import the Bootstrap CSS.

Import Bootstrap CSS in the `src/index.js` file:

```js
 import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
```

This gives you the styles. Preview here.

[image: hot]

**CodeSandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/client-x8dz3**